# Diaphragm pump with a solenoid valve

Tags: pump

I'm not sure if this suits here or in the EE forum. I am building a DIY fluid dispenser (milk, tea, etc) and I am testing the best way to dispense the liquid from the tank into cups. I'm using mini diaphragm valves because liquids like milk will have minimal negative impact to the internals.

To note - I have zero experience with plumbing.

What I found is even after the pump is stopped, there are leaks/dripping:

1. If the pump is below the level of the tank, after switching off the pump, the liquid keeps flowing. I presume it's due to siphon physics.
2. If the pump is above the tank, the flow stops, but the silicone pipe at the output (after the pump) keeps dripping. This is understandable and could in theory be mitigated with choosing a pipe with a smaller inner diameter.

Diaphragm pumps are one-directional so I cannot reverse-pump the residue liquid back to the tank.

One of my solutions is to add a small solenoid valve at the end of the pipe to stop any dripping/leaking. So to operate the dispenser, I would have to operate both the pump and the valve.

Is it a logical way forward or am I missing something?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about food service equipment, not DIY [diy.se] as described in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

Generally yes, an in-line valve is commonly used in this type of application. Most types of pump cannot be relied on to fully block flow when unpowered. Some leak much more than others, but most do leak.

You may be able to put the valve upstream of the pump, and continue to run the pump for a few seconds after closing the valve, in order to purge some of the liquid from the line - but even so, there'll probably be some residue which may be problematic with perishable fluids like milk.